# Stopping and later continuing a recursive tree traversal

Tags: javascript, recursion, google-apps-script, breadth-first-search

I'm using a <s>breadth-first</s> depth-first (?) search to map out files and folders. I'm also recording the mapped data, and building a JSON structure that shows the folders and their files/details.

I want to halt the execution at an arbitrary point, saving the JSON data, and then restarting the execution, and continuing from where I left off. Here is my code (This is Google Apps Script, essentially glorified cloud-executed JavaScript).

```
function MapDrive() {      
  var structure = {};
  try {    
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();

    getChildFolders(parentFolder, structure, {path: parentFolder.getName()});
    var blob = CreateJSONBlob(structure);
    MailApp.sendEmail('myEmail', 'Folder Tree', 'Drive Map Attached' ,{ attachments: [blob]})
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());   
  }
}

//Recursive breadth-first folder and file mapping
function TraverseDriveTree(parent, structure, path){
  if(CheckExecutionTime()){
    var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
    var parentName = parent.getName(); 

    //If there is no parent path add it
    if(typeof path[parentName] === 'undefined'){
      path[parentName] = {path: path.path};
    }

    //If parent doe snot exist in structure, then add it and it's files
    if(typeof structure[parentName] === 'undefined'){
      structure[parentName] = {};
      structure[parentName]['files'] = GetFilesInfo(parent.getFiles(), path[parentName].path);
    }  

    while (childFolders.hasNext()) {    
      var childFolder = childFolders.next();
      var childfolderName = childFolder.getName();  
      path[parentName][childfolderName] = {path: path[parentName].path + " > " +childfolderName};

      if(typeof structure[parentName][childfolderName] === 'undefined'){
        structure[parentName][childfolderName] = {};
      }

      structure[parentName][childfolderName]["files"] = GetFilesInfo(childFolder.getFiles(), path[parentName][childfolderName].path);

      // Recursive call for any sub-folders
      TraverseDriveTree(childFolder, structure[parentName][childfolderName], path[parentName]);    
    }     

  } else {
    SaveCurrentState(structure, parent, path)
  }
}
```

I do not need help with saving the JSON, or anything like that. I need help figuring out how to continue a recursive tree traversal after stopping it, and continuing to add items to the data structure from where I left off.

Comment: So, the `SaveCurrentState(structure, parent, path)` line is a key part of this?

Comment: Not particularly. I just save the JSON, and the current path. The real trouble is how you would go about restarting something recursive part way through, without traversing the whole tree again.

Comment: what you could do instead of doing recursive function calls is create a stack from an array that has the list of parent nodes yet to visit. push them onto your array on the way down and pop them off on the way up.

Comment: This kind of stack manipulation only works with continuation passing style. That's probably not what you want though.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK no JavaScript runtime gives you the kind of low-level access to manipulate the call stack that you would need to do what you're asking.

Your best bet is to use your own stack and skip the recursion altogether. It looks like you are doing a pre-order [tree traversal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), which can be done recursively as you are doing it but can also be done iteratively using a loop and a stack—and it is much easier to save and resume state for a loop than for the execution call stack.